# AJAX Toolkit login method only creates a 500 Server Error

Tags: javascript, soap-api, login, ajax-toolkit

I'm including apex.js and connection.js (version 32) in some javascript on a preview sandbox running spring'16. I'm trying to use

```
sforce.connection.login(username,passwordAndToken)
```

Unfortunately I'm getting only a 500 Server Error as response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap
/envelope/" xmlns:sf="urn:fault.partner.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <soapenv:Body>
            <soapenv:Fault>
                <faultcode>sf:UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION</faultcode>
                <faultstring>UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION : An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1506577276-236668 (237329493)
                </faultstring>
                <detail>
                    <sf:UnexpectedErrorFault xsi:type="sf:UnexpectedErrorFault">
                        <sf:exceptionCode>UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION</sf:exceptionCode>
                        <sf:exceptionMessage>An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1506577276-236668 (237329493)</sf:exceptionMessage>
                    </sf:UnexpectedErrorFault>
                </detail>
            </soapenv:Fault>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

The original POST generated by the ajax-toolkit is

```
<se:Envelope xmlns:se="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <se:Header xmlns:sfns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com">
        <sfns:SessionHeader>
            <sessionId>00Dg0000006T4d5!AQgAQMN1H3U.BslvD7qZXAZf9tSwLJqtuQAfju3emJR6s.RAsvTqyprtoUnruLZrjMVK9f_cmQLp15oyYCaQPhDoAAAAA_kp</sessionId>
        </sfns:SessionHeader>
        <sfns:DebuggingHeader>
            <debugLevel>Detail</debugLevel>
        </sfns:DebuggingHeader>
    </se:Header>
    <se:Body>
        <login xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:ns1="sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com">
            <username>**myUsername**</username>
            <password>**myPasswordAndToken**</password>
        </login>
    </se:Body>
</se:Envelope>
```

any idea why?